# prove the formula where $n=\prod_{i=1}^k p_{i}^{\alpha_i}$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, divisibility, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions

I have problems with fourth part of the exercise. Here we must prove the formula where $n=\prod_{i=1}^k p_{i}^{\alpha_i}$. How to prove, that $$\sigma_{-4}=\prod_{i=1}^k \frac{p_{i}^{4\alpha_i+4}-1}{p_{i}^{4\alpha_i+4}(p_i^4-1)}$$
I know that function $\sigma$ multiplicative, so  $\sigma_{-4}$ also will be multiplicative. $\sigma(n)$ means sum of positive divisors of n and here $\sigma_{-t}=\sum_{d|n, n>0}d^t$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your formula is a bit off; with your definition of $\sigma_{-t}$ it should in fact be
$$\sigma_{-4}=\prod_{i=1}^k \frac{p_{i}^{4\alpha_i+4}-1}{p_i^4-1}.$$
Though I should add, the usual definition differs from your by a sign; it is normally
$$\sigma_t:=\sum_{d\mid n,\ d>0}d^t.$$
With this definition you get the similar (but slightly different!) formula
$$\sigma_{-4}=\prod_{i=1}^k\frac{p_{i}^{-4\alpha_i-4}-1}{p_i^{-4}-1}=\prod_{i=1}^k \frac{p_{i}^{4\alpha_i+4}-1}{p_i^{4\alpha_i}(p^4-1)}.$$

---

**Hint:** Prove that for any integer $t$ you have
$$\sigma_{-t}=\prod_{i=1}^k\sum_{j=0}^{\alpha_i}(p_i^t)^j$$

**Alternative hint:** If  you know that $\sigma_{-4}$ is multiplicative, then it suffices to show that
$$\sigma_{-4}(p^{\alpha})=\frac{p^{4\alpha+4}-1}{p^{4\alpha}(p^4-1)},$$
for any prime $p$ and natural number $\alpha$. Of course by definition
$$\sigma_{-4}(p^{\alpha})=\sum_{j=0}^{\alpha}p^{4j}.$$

Comment: Yes, I tried in this way but didn't get given formula.

Comment: Where exactly did you get stuck? Sharing your efforts and progress makes it possible to help.